# How to convert the encoded value into another format

Tags: php

```
YTo2OntpOjA7czo0OiIyMDY3IjtpOjE7czo0OiIyMDY4IjtpOjI7czo0OiIyMDY5IjtpOjM7czo0OiIyMDcwIjtpOjQ7czo0OiIyMDcxIjtpOjU7czo0OiIyMDcyIjt9
```

The above is my encoded data.

When I try to decode it I am getting the output in this format:

```
a:6:{i:0;s:4:"2067";i:1;s:4:"2068";i:2;s:4:"2069";i:3;s:4:"2070";i:4;s:4:"2071";i:5;s:4:"2072";}
```

How can I convert it into this

```
["2067","2068","2069","2070","2071","2072"]
```

or this

```
(2067,2068,2069,2070,2071,2072)
```

?

Comment: Just `unserialize` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in your second block is serialised in PHP's object serialisation format. You can use the [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to turn it back into a PHP variable:

```
$data = 'a:6:{i:0;s:4:"2067";i:1;s:4:"2068";i:2;s:4:"2069";i:3;s:4:"2070";i:4;s:4:"2071";i:5;s:4:"2072";}';
$obj = unserialize($data);
echo json_encode($obj);
```

This outputs

```
["2067","2068","2069","2070","2071","2072"]
```

which is an array in the JSON format you requested.

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e9841c72950d44abd0ec6d45e2815cdcc89f42d